# Page Only Renders DataTable Header Not The Information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to pass a php array to JQuery and set a JQuery array to the php array to use as a source for my JQuery DataTable.

Everything seems to run sound, but when the page renders, I only get the header row displayed.  Why is my DataTable not displayed?

What changes should I make so that the DataTable displays and renders properly?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM demo_table LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>NumOfSales</th>
                    <th>SalesCurrent</th>
                    <th>Sales30Days</th>
                    <th>Sales60Days</th>
                    <th>Sales90Days</th>
                    <th>Sales120Days</th>
                    <th>TotalSales</th>
                    <th>ErrorDollarAmount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({
             data: information,
            columns: [
                { title: 'id' },
                { title: 'Name' },
                { title: 'NumOfSales' },
                { title: 'SalesCurrent' },
                { title: 'Sales30Days' },
                { title: 'Sales60Days' },
                { title: 'Sales90Days' },
                { title: 'Sales120Days' },
                { title: 'TotalSales' },
                { title: 'ErrorDollarAmount' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**EDIT**
I think I see part of the problem, when I view the page source it shows the below, which comments out all of the php **EXCEPT**the php that is being written on screen.

```php
<!-- Code Embed v2.3.2 -->
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM demo_table LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `$data[]` is a server-side PHP variable so the client-side JS won't have access to it. You need to perform an AJAX request to the server which should send back a JSON response - https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: @waterloomatt - This `var information = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>` will make PHP echo that variable as json in their JS code. They never try to use the PHP variable in JS.

Comment: Ahh - I missed that.

Comment: Please include your generated part of var information

Comment: @mike85 - what are you requesting to see?

Comment: @HotTomales only generated part of variable "information". You can see from browser view source code

Comment: @mike85 - see edit.  Does that provide what you are looking for?

Comment: How are you opening this file? Double clicking on it or through a web server? Do you have a web server installed? Do you have PHP installed? Is the above code a real copy/paste of your actual code or have you edited it when posting it here?

Comment: Where did you added the datatable.js

Comment: I have LAMP installed, and PHP installed and opening through IE.  I am editing to remove the database connection information but the rest is actual code I am using.

Comment: @Rishab - that is in the html header information.  It is included just not in the OP, SO was complaining about to much code so I removed it

Comment: @HotTomales in IE, when you view this code of page, right click and select "view source code". So we know wither your "var information = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;" became like this "var information = {....data here...}"

Comment: @mike85 - when I view page source it remains the same ```php
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Comment: @HotTomales did you use https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/ in your wordpress site to include PHP code because i saw "<!-- Code Embed v2.3.2 -->"?

Comment: @mike85 - it's auto-commenting out the php code.  If I'm reading the code embed page correctly, it says that it makes no difference for php code.  And yes, I have that plug-in installed :)

Comment: @HotTomales according plugin documentation, this only embeding html,js and css only. Not for server side script. That's why it does not work.

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Yes - the answer by @Rishab solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example for passing the data object to datatable using php json_encode() method

Even you were missing the **tbody** tag for the data table

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/izyq-3a7y

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<?php

$data = array(
    array('id'=>'parvez', 'Name'=>11, 'NumOfSales'=>101),
    array('id'=>'alam', 'Name'=>1, 'NumOfSales'=>102),
    array('id'=>'phpflow', 'Name'=>21, 'NumOfSales'=>103)       
    );

?>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>NumOfSales</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data)  ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
console.log(information)

        $('#my-table').dataTable({
            data: information,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'Name' },
                { data: 'NumOfSales' },

            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Changes in your current code should be like below:

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM demo_table LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="my-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>NumOfSales</th>
                    <th>SalesCurrent</th>
                    <th>Sales30Days</th>
                    <th>Sales60Days</th>
                    <th>Sales90Days</th>
                    <th>Sales120Days</th>
                    <th>TotalSales</th>
                    <th>ErrorDollarAmount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($data)  ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').dataTable({
            data: information,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'Name' },
                { data: 'NumOfSales' },
                { data: 'SalesCurrent' },
                { data: 'Sales30Days' },
                { data: 'Sales60Days' },
                { data: 'Sales90Days' },
                { data: 'Sales120Days' },
                { data: 'TotalSales' },
                { data: 'ErrorDollarAmount' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Same result as my issue.  Prints the header and this on screen ```php
fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { $data[] = $row; } mysqli_free_result($result); mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: @HotTomales - Are you saying that you see the PHP code on the page when you're visiting it from the browser? That should have been included in the question since that's a _completely_ different issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - yes not all of the code, only the lines pasted above in the comment

Comment: @HotTomales - Please edit your question to include _all_ info. If you see that PHP code, then it 
isn't being executed at all, which means that your JS can't possibly get the correct data.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - see my edit.  Viewing the page source it seems MOST of the php code I'm trying to execute is being commented out for some reason.

Comment: I have added the phpfiddle link of working data table code please check in  my answer